# What's your most succinct way of checking param existence + value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an optional URL param, say "user_id" I need to check for. I know I can use

`if params.has_key?(:user_id) ...`

to do things based on the presence of the `user_id` parameter, but sometimes `user_id` is passed without a value, so I want to ignore it completely. To fight the issue, I find myself doing this a lot--but there's got to be a better way, right?

```
if params[:user_id] && !params[:user_id].empty?
  # Do stuff
end
```

It just seems really ugly.

Comment: Why not params[:user_id].present?

Comment: sigh. yep. much better. sorry I couldn't find that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're just checking if `params[:user_id]` is present, then you can try:

```
if params[:user_id].present?
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: Great answer that does exactly what I want--I just wish semantically it was more descriptive. IMO the word "present" implies it exists as a parameter but could possibly be nil.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)?

```
if params.fetch(:user_id, nil).present?
  # Do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Often I need to check presence of

```
params {"shoes" => {"number" => "11"}}
```

when I don't know if hash "shoes" exists (maybe was created dinamically !).
If I try to call params[:shoes][:number] where params[:shoes] is nil I'll trigger an undefined exception.

Using **raise** I can check directly params[:shoes][:number] without trigger an exception.

```
if(params[:shoes][:number] raise false)
  # here you can safe reading params[:shoes][:number]
  # managing exception if params[:shoes] (or [:shoes][:number]) is nil
end
```

I hope this helpful